# Jstock: /usr/bin doesn't exist even if it exists

Tags: java, home-directory, finance

Ubuntu: 14.04.4 LTS
Java Version: 1.8.0_74

I installed Jstock (1.0.7.13) via this:
http://jstock.org/help_install_upgrade.html#install-linux
So I start the programm via `./jstock.sh`

When I start Jstock I get:

> Warning: /usr/bin does not exist

Then the program starts.

Even if the folder obviously exist, and also I found `/usr/share/java`, so this also exists.
When I type `whereis java` it says:

> java: /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

The `jstock.sh` file says:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Normally, editing this script should not be required.
# Only case is to set up JAVA_HOME if it's not already defined.
#
# To specify an alternative JVM, edit and uncomment the following 
# line and change the path accordingly.
#JAVA_HOME=/usr/share/java

_JAVA_EXEC="java"
if [ -n $JAVA_HOME ] ; then
    _TMP="$JAVA_HOME/usr/bin"
    if [ -f "$_TMP" ] ; then
        if [ -x "$_TMP" ] ; then
            _JAVA_EXEC="$_TMP"
        else
            echo "Warning: $_TMP is not executable"
        fi
    else
        echo "Warning: $_TMP does not exist"
    fi
fi
if ! which "$_JAVA_EXEC" >/dev/null ; then
    echo "Error: No Java Runtime Environment found"
    echo "Please set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to the root       directory of your SUN Java installation, e.g. by editing the 7th line in this     launcher script."
    exit 1
fi

#
# Resolve the location of the JStock installation.
# This includes resolving any symlinks.
PRG=$0
while [ -h "$PRG" ]; do
    ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
    link=`expr "$ls" : '^.*-> \(.*\)$' 2>/dev/null`
    if expr "$link" : '^/' 2> /dev/null >/dev/null; then
        PRG="$link"
    else
        PRG="`dirname "$PRG"`/$link"
    fi
done

JSTOCK_BIN=`dirname "$PRG"`
cd "${JSTOCK_BIN}"

_VMOPTIONS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m"
$_JAVA_EXEC $_VMOPTIONS -jar jstock.jar
```

The program works fine, but since I want to use it in reality I want the program to fully function, without any error.

btw: How can I write here like a normal human being? I made weird spaces to avoid writing everything in one line. Thx !

Comment: Check this link http://askubuntu.com/editing-help . It will help you to edit your post properly.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the line `_TMP="$JAVA_HOME/usr/bin` to `_TMP="$JAVA_HOME/usr/bin/java` works for me.